# :hover, :focus, :deactivated?

Tags: css

Does there like :hover and :focus exist a simular thing for deactivated inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input[disabled="disabled"]` Will work (this is an attribute selector).

You can read more about attribute selectors at http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: how would you write the class in the css file?

Comment: `.myform input[disabled="disabled"] { display:none; }` or `.myform .text-box[disabled="disabled"] { display:none; }` are two examples.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me.. `input.inp input[disabled="disabled"] {
 background:#ff0000;
}`

Comment: write it like this: `input.inp[disabled="disabled"] { background:#ff0000; }`  Your rule says "input elements that are disabled inside of input elements with the class inp should..." which certainly isn't want you mean.

Comment: hmm... it only works in IE8.. and neither in Chrome nor Firefox

Comment: That should not be the case. The attribute selector is compatible with all browsers back to ie7, see this fiddle for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/KQvU7/

Comment: This is probably a situation with your specific stylesheet. Make sure you don't have a rule with a higher specificity that is hiding the styles in your disabled rule.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always give your deactivated elements a special CSS class, e.g. `deactivated` and then assign properties to this class (e.g. `.deactivated:hover` etc.).